# synonyms for 'professional'

Tags: synonyms, connotation

I am looking for a synonym for the adjective "professional" as it is sometimes used to mean "of high quality" or "projecting confidence & skill" when describing the perception of a group of people by the public.

I'm in a musical group that strives to put forth a "professional" image in terms of musical quality, visual appearance, and interaction with the public during and after a performance.  But, since our members are not paid, we are not professionals in the strict sense.   I sometimes have to advise our members how to conduct themselves, so I'm looking for a good word to use in place of saying "be professional" or "that looks professional".    Obviously I don't want to say "look amateurish", even though we are, in fact, amateurs.

I appreciate the answers suggested below which might be useful.  We're not a grunge band; the group is a Japanese taiko drumming group which is supposed to operate with a measure of self-discipline, so 'classy' might be suitable.  To give some specific examples of where I would normally use "professional":  1.  "Chewing gum in public makes us look unprofessional."  and 2.  "Having a dedicated email address with our group name looks more professional than @hotmail.com or @gmail.com".    The reason I'm looking for alternatives is that I once made a suggestion that the group do something "professionally" only to have one member (who has a contrary and difficult personality) snarkily reply, "We're not a professional group."

Comment: didn't you just give several phrases that you could use, including "professional?"

Comment: "Professional" seems to have become so much a signifier of *class* that you might as well just settle for "classy." It is wonderfully odd when you think about it, how *amateur* just a century ago carried higher-class connotations than *professional,* but now that has completely reversed.

Comment: Would "expert" work? It allows you to refer to the skill of your non-professionals without the implication that it's expertise they're paid for.

Comment: Not a noun but using an adjective, you could tell your group members to be couth (Cultured, refined, and well mannered).

Answer (score 2):

The figurative sense of *professional* that you describe is perfectly fine, as long as you're careful how you use it--for example, you can describe yourselves as "projecting a professional appearance."

If that's not a satisfactory answer, consider using different words in different contexts: you have a *refined* appearance, give a *polished* performance, are *classy* in your interactions with the public, and *responsible* in your dealings with booking agents.

Answer (score 1):

**professionalism** http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/professionalism

This gives you the *professional style* you are looking for without the common connotation of being paid for your services to make a living (although it can still mean that).

Other alternatives:

masterful

peerless

precision

honed craftsmanship/craft/craft-work

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **[top tier](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/top-tier)** (sometimes *top-tier*) is often used to describe someone or something that demonstrates a high level within its field, regardless of whether there is payment for the goods or services rendered.

> Of the highest level or quality

Similarly, *[top-notch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/top-notch)*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some combinations of these:

**high-class**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/high-class

> of a type superior in quality or degree; first-rate: a high-class hotel.

**classy**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/classy

> of high class, rank, or grade

**class**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/class

> adjective
>   26.
>   Informal. of high quality, integrity, status, or style: class players on a mediocre team.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that the type of band has to factor into this. I mean, I don't know any grunge bands or punks bands who want to call themselves "classy."

I think a good word would be one that suggest the band is on the rise, here are some:

up-and-coming

> up-and-com·ing [uhp-uhn-kuhm-ing]
>
> likely to succeed; bright and industrious: *an up-and-coming young executive.*

emerging

> e·merge
>   verb (used without object), e·merged, e·merg·ing.
>   1.to come forth into view or notice, as from concealment or obscurity: a ghost emerging > from the grave; a ship emerging from the fog.

rising

> ris·ing
>   1. going up, increasing, or sloping upward.